# How to run react app and headless Wordpress and React App on same server (managed by plesk)?

Tags: multisite

0

I am pretty new in website and server stuff and i have a question:

I have an react app and it should be the main and only website I want to reach under www.example.com, and I want to use Wordpress just headless (wp db and wordpress REST API) but on the same server. Server is managed by Plesk.

As far as I understood, Wordpress has to be installed in my servers document root, e.g. /httpdocs/.

But when I want to reach my react app under www.example.com, I have to deploy the build folder content also into /httpdocs/, which interfers with wordpress. In this case if I go to www.example.com, I get the wordpress site.

When I have my react app in another folder, e.g. /github/build/, and set this folder my document root, the page is accessible under www.example.com, but wordpress is not reachable anymore (www.example.com/wp-login.php not found).

The only ugly way it seems for me it can work is if I deploy the build folder into the wordpress root directory, but then the react app is only acessible under www.example.com/build (only guessing).

Is there a way to make it work as wanted?

Comment: You could just put WordPress in a subdirectory. If you're running it headless you don't necessarily need it in the root. So you could have it at http://example.com/wp or http://example.com/api or something.

Comment: Many thanks. I will go for that solution.